# How can I join 2 cells in a table while retrieving data from database from PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to display time table (which store in the database-MySQL) in a web page using PHP. I can simply display it by using table. but one cell represent one hour.so for two hours lectures how can I merge 2 cells if adjacent cells include same subject? Please help me. 
Further I should display those cells as text boxes and I should able to select those cells.
This is my code for display time table.

```
mysqli_select_db($connect,"timetable");

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from 3yeariit2");


echo"<table border='1'>";
    echo"<tr><th>Time</th>";
    echo"<th>Monday</th>";
    echo"<th>Tuesday</th>";
    echo"<th>Wednesday</th>";
    echo"<th>Thursday</th>";
    echo"<th>Friday</th>";
    echo"</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $time = $row["time"];
    $monday = $row["monday"];
    $tuesday = $row["tuesday"];
    $wednesday = $row["wednesday"];
    $thursday = $row["thursday"];
    $friday = $row["friday"];

    echo"<tr><td>$time</td>";
        echo"<td>$monday</td>";
        echo"<td>$tuesday</td>";
        echo"<td>$wednesday</td>";
        echo"<td>$thursday</td>";
        echo"<td>$friday</td>";
    echo"</tr>";    
}
echo"</table>";
```

For example among others, CST 391-2 [D1] should merge both 3.00-5.00 time slot in the image below

[image]

The method should be possible to apply in loading any other time table. Because I should display more time tables.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: How does the result look like and how should it look like?

Comment: Mergin cell of same row or same column?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm new to stackoverflow. I have insert an image of how it looks like now. but can you see that? I need to merge 2 cells in same column only if same subject in adjacent cells.

Comment: @Odin Merge cells of same column. But they should merge only if same subject in near cells.

Comment: What should be merged?

Comment: @mplungjan According to my example image the CST 391-2 [D1] shouls merge both 3.00-5.00 time slot. other subjects also like wise.

Comment: Please update your question with such information. I do not have to do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just added time as single string in database and columns for days. Where as the better way is creating start time and end time as separate columns as per below.

```
subjectcode | subjectname | start | end | ...
```

Then you can easily add 2 hours subject using one row.

But in this case you can check next related subject and if the subject is same do the [html row span](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan). Thereafter in next iteration you need to skip adding `<td>` if particular subject was already printed using previous iteration.

I just explained the logic not the code. Hope it helps..

Comment: yes. First I thought of that logic and started. But when coding it is not that much easy. I will try your first idea. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "colspan" or "rowspan" properties to merge rows or columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use "colspan" for merge more then one column and "rowspan" for merge more than one rows :

Like :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2"> </td>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```